# Loading larger than memory data into bcolz from Redshift

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, amazon-redshift, bcolz

I would like to save the output of a redshift query locally. I have tried using `blaze/odo` but with default settings that tries to load all the data into memory before writing and trying to stream the data throws other errors, described another question: [Streaming results with Blaze and SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326424/streaming-results-with-blaze-and-sqlalchemy)

Since that question does not have any answers, I am looking for an alternative way to do this.

**What is a simple, reliable and reasonably efficient way of loading larger than memory query result into bcolz from Redshift?**

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but I'll answer it to help if someone with the same problem stumble upon it. I assume you use Blaze to access Redshift. You'll have to partition table on some column and do it iteratively, like this:

```
import blaze as bz
table = bz.Data('postgresql://server@example.com::table_name')
val_list = bz.odo(table['column_name'].distinct(), list)
np_dtype = table.schema[0].to_numpy_dtype()
for val in val_list:
    table_partition = table[table['column_name'] == val]
    partition_len = int(table_partition.count())
    bcolz.fromiter(table_partition, np_dtype, partition_len,
                   rootdir='rootdir_for_partition', mode='w',
                   cparams=compression_params)
```

and than use bcolz.walk to iterate over result.